# Is it valid to have <input type="checkbox"> between <th> </th>?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a checkbox in the HTML table header such as:

```
<th id="CHECKED">
    <input id="check-all" type="checkbox" onClick="javascript:checkAll(this);" class="check-all" />
</th>
```

When I click on the checkbox my browser says that my function "checkAll" is not defined.

Can anyone please advise why I am getting this error?

Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/A7Wts/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/A7Wts/4/ (Set sidebar on left to `No Wrap - in <head>`)

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether an input can exist within table headers (which it can), but more of why are you getting a JavaScript error.

Comment: It Works: http://jsfiddle.net/A7Wts/5/ (1) Inline event handlers are a no no (2) When using inline handlers, your code should be in head or body.

Comment: What j08691 said. I moved your script into a script tag above the table and it works http://jsfiddle.net/2d2JQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691), *It has nothing to do with whether an input can exist within table headers (which it can), but more of why are you getting a JavaScript error*

In your code, I can see your function `checkAll()` its getting defined under scope of `$(document).ready()`.

So, It won't be accessible from outside and will throw `Undefined` exception.

> > Change location of function declaration to somewhere globally

```
<script>
    function checkAll(pThis) {
        console.log($(pThis).is(':checked') ? "is checked" : "not checked" );
    }
</script>
```

It will work

Check this **[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7Wts/7/)**.

Comment: +1: Scope. Also, its not really required to be before the checkbox. It can be anywhere as long as it is accessible when the inline handler is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the formal syntax, any `input` element is valid as a child of a `th` element. Whether it makes sense is a different issue. A `th` element should contain header information for a column or a row. It is difficult to see how a mere checkbox would do that. What header information could it convey?

It seems that your real problem is very different, but I answered to the question asked in the title.